# Canvas Repaint After Downloading the Image

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Creating a J2ME application.
PROBLEM:how i repainting the displayed canvas without ant user event.

Trying to display canvas page,page contains text and image.first time we display text and local image in screen,after displaying it downloading the actuall image form internet and save in RMS,completion of download we are setting one flag.After downloading how can i repaint newly download image with displayed canvas without any user interface.

Please give me some solution.

Thanks and Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

[Canvas.repaint()](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#repaint%28%29) method is invented exactly to serve the purpose like you describe.

Check the API javadocs for more details if you're interested